# SoftLayer Command Line Interface - Can't create a private network only machine from slcli

Tags: python-3.x, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

The command below works and machines are creating on the right private VLAN .. **BUT!!!** They are coming with a public VLAN too even though I don't want that .. command so far that works:

```
slcli vs create --billing=hourly --image=1060669 --hostname=ejkpoc --domain=ejk.co.uk --cpu=1 --memory=1 --datacenter=lon02 --postinstall=https://10.1.1.13/files/bootstrap-rhel-5.sh --vlan-private=1227409
```

The major trouble with the assignment of a public for me is that all of the postinstall bootstrap with attaches to Chef etc. is now registering the FQDN of the public! Cheers EJK

Answer (score 0):

I didn't "RTFM" correctly ... my bad ... in the options there is a "--private" to force the machine to be private only (see the middle of the picture DOH!!) ... running the command now ...

[image]

I will update with the command once it works ...

Cheers
EJK